# Performing multiple inserts for a single row in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I have a table containing data that i need to migrate into another table with a linking table. This is a one time migration as part of an upgrade.

I have a company table that contains records relating to a company and a contact person.
I want to migrate the contact details into another table and link the new person with a linking table

Consider I have this table which is already populated

tblCompany

- CompanyId
- CompanyName
- RegNo
- ContactForename
- ContactSurname

And i want to migrate the contact person data to

tblPerson

- PersonID (identitycolumn)
- Forename
- Surname

and use the identity column resulting and insert it into the linking table

tblCompanyPerson

- CompanyId
- PersonId

I've tried a few different ways to approach this using cursors and output variables into a temp table but none seem right to me (or give me the solution...)

The closest i have got is to have a companyID on tblPerson and insert companyId into it and output the new personId and the companyId into a temp table. Then loop through the temp table to create the tblCompanyContact.

example

```
declare @companycontact TABLE (companyId int, PersonId int)

insert into tblPerson
    (Forename,
    Surname,
    CompanyID)
output inserted.CompanyID, INSERTED.PersonID into @companycontact
select  
    ContactPersonForeName, 
    ContactPersonSurename,  
    CompanyID
from tblCompany c


insert into tblCompanyPerson
    (CompanyID,
    PersonID)
select c.companyId, PersonId from @companycontact c
```

**Background**

- Im using MS SQL Server 2008 R2
- The tblPerson is already populated with hundreds of thousands of
  records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'trick' using `MERGE` statement to achieve mapping between newly inserted and source values:

```
MERGE tblPerson trgt
USING tblCompany src ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN INSERT 
    (Forename, Surename)
    VALUES (src.ContactPersonForeName, src.ContactPersonSurename)
OUTPUT  src.CompanyID, INSERTED.PersonID
INTO  tblCompanyPerson (CompanyId, PersonID);
```

That 1=0 condition is to always get everything from source. You might want to replace  it  or even whole source with some sub-query to actually check whatever you already have same person mapped.

EDIT: [Here is some reading about using `MERGE` and `OUTPUT`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/24/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge.aspx)

Comment: This looks like the perfect solution! I have combined this with creating a view for the src data and it seems like the solution i need.

Comment: In the end i didnt need the view i fugured out how to add clauses to the source query using the WHEN

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know what SQL you are using its difficult to decide if this is correct. i also don't know if you already tried this but it's the best idea i have:

```
insert into tblPerson
(Forename, Surename)
Select ContactForename, ContactPersonSurename
from tblCompany

insert into tblCompanyPerson
(CompanyID, PersonID)
select CompanyId, PersonID 
from tblPerson, tblCompany
where ContactForename = Forename and ContactPersonSurename = Surename
```

Sarajog

Comment: The problem is there are hundreds of thousands of records existing in the person table and there is no guarantee that another person doesn't already exist.

Comment: Im using MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: All the contacts need to be inserted as a new person. There will be no merging or searching etc.

Comment: if I'm not wrong you can iterate throug a select statement so why don't you just insert the data into the tblPerson and insert into the tblCompanyPerson the CompanyID and the last LAST_INSERT_ID()?